# ^^I in code segment when using Minted

Tags: minted

I want to include a code segment, which is written in Go. I did use the `minted` package for it. But, when I copy paste the code from my editor to Texmaker, the tabs are actually displayed as `^^I`. Here is a small screenshot for it: http://prntscr.com/gb78ou

I don't have anything fancy there, just this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{colorful}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{go}
func ntt(a *[N]uint16, omega *[N/2]uint16) {
    for level := uint(0); level < 8; level++ {
        for start := uint(0); start < (1 << level); start++ {
            jTwiddle := 0
            for j := start; j < N-1; j += 2 * (1 << level) {
                W := omega[jTwiddle]
                jTwiddle++
                temp := a[j]
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Any idea how to make the `^^I` disappear from the code segment?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Is your minted up-to-date?

Comment: What engine are you using? `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue when compiling the file with XeLaTeX. You should use the `-8bit` option:

```
xelatex -8bit -shell-escape filename
```

You should also add `\setminted{tabsize=4}` (the default value is 8).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{colorful}

\setminted{tabsize=4}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{go}
func ntt(a *[N]uint16, omega *[N/2]uint16) {
    for level := uint(0); level < 8; level++ {
        for start := uint(0); start < (1 << level); start++ {
            jTwiddle := 0
            for j := start; j < N-1; j += 2 * (1 << level) {
                W := omega[jTwiddle]
                jTwiddle++
                temp := a[j]
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

With the `-8bit` command line option I get

[image]

Without the option

[image]